# Where can I find an open source augmented reality framework for Android?

Tags: android, open-source, augmented-reality

Does anyone know if there is any existing open source framework for augmented reality which could be used for Android applications?

Comment: StackExchange proposal: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/30436/augmented-reality

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [AndAR](http://code.google.com/p/andar/) with a GNU license

Answer (score 0):

This is another option: https://github.com/mixare/mixare

"mixare (mix Augmented Reality Engine) is a free open source augmented reality browser, which is published under the GPLv3"