# Is there any open source Augmented Reality sdk for android?

Tags: android, sdk, augmented-reality

I' ve found this question on StackOverflow but the two sdk mentioned looks really old (about 4 and 2 years ago):

[Where can I find an open source augmented reality framework for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5702275/where-can-i-find-an-open-source-augmented-reality-framework-for-android)

Do you know if exist some over open source Augmented Reality sdk for Android?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: This looks free (but not opensource): https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/android

Comment: If you need to implement **marker based augmented reality** then marker based droid example is better to understand plz download source code from below link https://github.com/bitstars/droidar                   This application is just used opencv open source library.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This page http://socialcompare.com/en/comparison/augmented-reality-sdks also contains a lot of AR frameworks (maybe too much).

Comment: Such a great and helpful link. I have read all the SDK and finally choose "Vuforia" from the list because this is easy to use and open source.

Answer (score 7):

`Vuforia SDK` is one of the best `Augmented Reality` 3rd party sdk. Even they have provided some sample application and also have a active forum where you can ask your query.Following is the official link,

https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/sdk/android

Another promising `Augmented Reality` SDk is `AndAR` which is open source too.Following is the link

https://code.google.com/p/andar/

Comment: Well, seems like you posted this about 20 secs before me :P as i said in the other comment this sdk is free but not opensource :( Thanks for sharing bytheway :)

Comment: @FedericoPonzi: My mistake buddy, you can use `AndAR` sdk which is open source.See my edit.

Comment: As i said in the question, the two sdk cited in the other question i linked (AndAR - 4 years and mixare - 2 years) looks old so i was looking for something more fresh :P thanks!

Answer (score 4):

AndAR is not the state of the art option, but it works very well if you want to create a marker based application with an open source SDK.

As mentioned, Vuforia is an excellent free option to create more sophisticate applications, including markerless apps. Another one is the Metaio SDK. It is also free a have more features than Vuforia.

There is another link that compares AR SDK: https://creator.zoho.com/reitmayr/augmented-reality-sdks/view-embed/AR_SDKs

Comment: Neither of these SDK is free right now. Only Vuforia has free Unity option but thats all. They are "free" for testing and develping but if you want to publish your app you will have to pay... a lot. Source: https://developer.vuforia.com/vui/pricing     
https://sites.google.com/site/metaiosuite/